# Notify Users When Record Hasn't Been Updated in X Amount of Time

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, cron, delayed-job, resque

I'm working on a Rails 3.2 application where users create, read and update  multiple kinds of reports. We use MySQL and Redis.

I would like to notify users when one of their reports hasn't been updated in the previous X months by showing them notifications on their profile/dashboard page in the browser.

I would prefer to do this asynchronously.

At some point, I would also like to have live, in-app notifications so users can be notified when a report they're watching has been updated or someone likes their report. Conceptually, I was contemplating the best way of going about doing this...

1. A cron job that runs a SQL query and retrieves all reports that have update_at fields older than 3 months, and creates a notification record linked to that user and report. A new notification record will be created only if user didn't have an existing notification.
2. A background job, using something like Resque that checks the database periodically throughout the day. Notifications are stored in a queue. This seems like it would scale better into a more robust, in-app notifications feature.

Are these my only two options? **Is there a better asynchronous way to listen to the database, and notify a user when one of their records hasn't been updated in 3 months?** Is some implementation of websockets necessary here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you necessarily need to use CPU cycles with some always-running background job, but that depends on how powerful you want these notifications to be. If you want them to be real-time, and you plan on using a publisher-subscriber model in the future then I'd [consider a redis + node server setup.](https://github.com/thoughtshop/rails-node-redis-pubsub)

The complexity of websockets means more implementation time. Will that extra time spent really benefit you? If it's very important that your notifications be asynchronous and real-time, like exchanging messages in a chat app or getting pop-up notifications on Facebook, then this is the right choice.

However, if all you really want to do is let users know when their reports are past a certain age, when they request their profile page, a cron that runs every couple of hours will be much easier to implement. You could even use Google Analytics to get a feel for when users are putting the heaviest burden on your app, and schedule the job around that.

First, create a rake task that completes the behavior your described above--check for old reports and create notifications. Put that in your app's `lib/tasks` directory. And then write a cron job like so:

`$ 0 6,12,18 * * * cd /path/to/app && bundle exec rake task_name`

This task will run 3x a day, at 6am, 12pm and 6pm.

From there, if you want to create an activity feed for your users, you could also implement a synchronous pub-sub solution pretty simply. E.g., User A subscribes to User B's reports, User B publishes a new report, after_save callback to create a notification for User A. This will be slower, it won't be live, but if it's a small app and this feature isn't a core part, then this makes better use of your time than the other options.